# Android - Recreate the viewPager by method inside the Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a databases with some rows. For every row there's a fragment inside a ViewPager.
Inside the fragment, I have a Button that deletes the row in the DB. 
What I want is to recreate also the ViewPager, so the page with the old db row is not shown anymore.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: The ViewPager is feeded by a PageAdapter, right? you can call your getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: mmm I'm not sure to understand. I should call a method like this inside the fragment inside the ViewPager, but I've not a getAdapter() method here..

Comment: The ViewPager is the one with that method. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getAdapter%28%29